# How to improve the Magic Find?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the patch 2.0.1, you no longer can improve your MF with Paragon Level or Nephalem Valor buff.

So is there a way to improve that stats without raising the difficulty level or playing in coop ?

Comment: Yeah but answers there are not valid anymore

Comment: I'm aware of that, but that still doesn't mean it isn't a dupe.  Ask for updates on the answers, or better yet, place a bounty on the question.

Comment: Z -  Started an update bounty there so it should be updated soon.